# Compare the Sheet1 column A values with Sheet2 column B, if match then Sheet2.Col C=Sheet1.Col A and Sheet2.Col D=True

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare the Sheet1 column A values with Sheet2 column B, if match then i want to put the Sheet1 Column A values in Sheet2 Column C.
and column D should be populated with 'True' 
So i have written the below code:

```
Sub val() 
Dim sheet1_last_rec_cnt As Long 
Dim sheet2_last_rec_cnt As Long 
Dim sheet1_col1_val As String 
Dim cnt1 As Long 
Dim cnt2 As Long 
sheet1_last_rec_cnt = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
sheet2_last_rec_cnt = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
For cnt1 = 2 To sheet1_last_rec_cnt 
sheet1_col1_val = Sheet1.Range("A" & cnt1).Value 
For cnt2 = 2 To sheet2_last_rec_cnt 
If sheet1_col1_val = Sheet2.Range("B" & cnt2).Value Then 
Sheet2.Range("C" & cnt2).Value = sheet1_col1_val 
Sheet2.Range("D" & cnt2).Value = "True" 
Exit For 
End If 
Next 
Next 
End Sub
```

Problem is i have one millions of records in both the sheets. 
if i use the above code then For loop is running (One million * One million) times. So excel is hanging like anything. 
Can someone please help me to optimize the code?

Comment: Are any of the values duplicates or is every one unique?

Answer (score 0):

For 1 million records I'm not sure Excel is the best place to be storing this data. If your code is designed to tidy up the data so that you can export it to a database then great ... if not, then, well, I fear rough seas lay ahead for you.

The code below will speed things up a touch as it only loops through each column once, and it populates a collection of unique values so that it only has to check against that instead of the whole column each time. If you sorted your rows then it could be made even quicker but I'll leave that one for you.

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim uniques As Collection
    Dim sourceValues As Variant
    Dim targetValues As Variant
    Dim sourceItem As String
    Dim targetItem As String
    Dim sourceCount As Long
    Dim targetCount As Long
    Dim matches As Boolean
    Dim output() As Variant

    ' Acquire the values to be compared.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        sourceValues = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        targetValues = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    'Resize the output array to size of target values array.
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(targetValues, 1), 1 To 2)

    sourceCount = 1
    Set uniques = New Collection

    'Iterate through the target values to find a match in the source values
    For targetCount = 1 To UBound(targetValues, 1)

        targetItem = CStr(targetValues(targetCount, 1))
        matches = Contains(uniques, targetItem)

        If Not matches Then

            'Continue down the source sheet to check the values.
            Do While sourceCount <= UBound(sourceValues, 1)

                sourceItem = CStr(sourceValues(sourceCount, 1))
                sourceCount = sourceCount + 1

                'Add any new values to the collection.
                If Not Contains(uniques, sourceItem) Then uniques.Add True, sourceItem

                'Check for a match and leave the loop if we found one.
                If sourceItem = targetItem Then
                    matches = True
                    Exit Do
                End If

            Loop

        End If

        'Update the output array if there's a match.
        If matches Then
            output(targetCount, 1) = targetItem
            output(targetCount, 2) = True
        End If

    Next

    'Write output array to the target sheet.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Resize(UBound(targetValues, 1), 2).value = output

End Sub
Private Function Contains(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    'Function to test if the key already exists.
    Contains = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Contains = col(key)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```